# Javascript reducer, how to stop && operator resetting values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, reducers

Hobbyist coder here, new to reducers.

I have an app that adds objects into an array, with reducers that capture the quantity of each object's value of position.

The below works to an extent, that when I add two 'Att' entities the quantity of totalAtt equates to two, but when I add another position value the totalAtt quantity is reset to zero. Likewise for all values of position.

Discovered the && operator is resetting my initial value to false, given its boolean nature.

Anyone know how to tweak the code to capture the quantites without the values resetting?

```
    const totalGK = get(team).reduce(
        (a, b) => b.position === "GK" && a + b.qty,
        0
    );
    const totalDef = get(team).reduce(
        (a, b) => b.position === "Def" && a + b.qty,
        0
    );
    const totalMid = get(team).reduce(
        (a, b) => b.position === "Mid" && a + b.qty,
        0
    );
    const totalAtt = get(team).reduce(
        (a, b) => b.position === "Att" && a + b.qty,
        0
    );

    return {
        totalGK,
        totalDef,
        totalMid,
        totalAtt
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reducing, you always return the new value of the accumulator. In your case, you add a value to the previous accumulator to get the new value. So you should always take `a` (the accumulator), and add 0 (`b.position === something` is `false, so it's casted to 0)` or the number if the condition is `true`.

```
const totalGK = get(team).reduce(
  (a, b) => a + (b.position === "GK" && b.qty),
  0
);
const totalDef = get(team).reduce(
  (a, b) => a + (b.position === "Def" && b.qty),
  0
);
const totalMid = get(team).reduce(
  (a, b) => a + (b.position === "Mid" && b.qty),
  0
);
const totalAtt = get(team).reduce(
  (a, b) => a + (b.position === "Att" && b.qty),
  0
);
```

However, there is a shorter and more readable way to approach this, reduce the `team` to an object, using the `position` values as keys, and add the `qty` to the previous value of the key. To get the consts, destructure the object created by reduce, and use 0 as the default values.

Example:

```js
const get = arr => arr;

const team = [{ position: 'GK', qty: 2 }, { position: 'GK', qty: 2 }, { position: 'GK', qty: 2 }, { position: 'Att', qty: 3 }, { position: 'Att', qty: 3 }, { position: 'Att', qty: 3 }];

const {
  GK: totalGK = 0,
  Def: totalDef = 0,
  Mid: totalMid = 0,
  Att: totalAtt = 0,
} = get(team).reduce((acc, obj) => ({
  ...acc,
  [obj.position]: (acc[obj.position] || 0) + obj.qty
}), {});

console.log(totalGK); // 6
console.log(totalDef); // 0
console.log(totalMid); // 0
console.log(totalAtt); // 9
```

Answer (score -1):

It would work better using a ternary operator, so you always return a value from your function. Something like this

```
const totalGK = get(team).reduce(
  (a, b) => b.position === "GK" ? a + b.qty : a,
   0
);
```